# "functions: not found" during "gcloud app deploy"

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-functions, actions-on-google

I am new to deploying action webhooks into GCP, and trying to simply deploy the demo api.ai webhook from here: https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-webhook-template-nodejs

Using the instructions from here: https://developers.google.com/actions/samples/

Though I recently noted this pages says "These instructions assume you are using Google App Engine". Not a useful sentence in a Samples / Getting Started page...

When I run `gcloud app deploy`, it does something for a couple of minutes, then ends with:

(Note that I have hidden part of some keys with 'x's. Not sure what's sensitive, if any):

```
$ gcloud app deploy
You are about to deploy the following services:
 - level-up-xxxx/default/20170625t233004 (from [/home/peter/Projects__/xxxx/webhook/app.yaml])
     Deploying to URL: [https://level-up-xxxx.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  y

If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.                                                        

Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Building and pushing image for service [default]

... {DETAILS OMITTED FROM HERE} ...

57fff86xxxxx: Pushed
c4a3d3bxxxxx: Pushed
90c3ed3xxxxx: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:6d06015bb56b73145d91884a477463d5bef03dfb24882a07ce46492bxxxxxxxx size: 2626
DONE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                   
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] 
Application startup error:

> level-up-xxxx@0.0.1 start /app
> functions deploy level-up-xxxx --trigger-http

sh: 1: functions: not found

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/nodejs/bin/node" "/nodejs/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
...
```

This appears to have occurred from an attempted "npm start" (Presumably on the GCP server, right?)

What is `functions`?

Is this something that is supposed to exist in the environment in GCP that I am deploying to?

It seems I am not the only one encountering this. Also an issue at the github page for the demo I am trying: https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-webhook-template-nodejs/issues/1

UPDATE1: I discovered that I didn't have the 'Cloud Functions API' enabled for the relevant GCP project. Strangely, enabling this seems to have made **no difference**. (When discovered, I thought this was my problem for sure! But no...)

UPDATE2: I also discovered that the 'deploy' commands here seem to want the (exported) function name, NOT the project name, so I have changed from "deploy level-up-xxx" to "deploy levelUpXxxx". But still no joy.

UPDATE3: I came across this 'older' sequence of commands which is still documented at: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/http
Seems to **succeed** at deploying: (But I haven't yet confirmed this is sufficiently equivalennt to the 'app deploy' I am trying to get working)

**(@Prisoner tells me these are not 'older' but a different GCP thing altogether...)**

```
$ gsutil mb gs://level-up-xxxx
$ gcloud beta functions deploy LevelUpXxxx --stage-bucket level-up-xxxx --trigger-http
```

Still want/need to get the advertised (non-beta) "gcloud app deploy" thing to work...

Very confused about what's going on...

Could the version of npm I am using at my desktop be an issue? i.e. Too new?
 Could that be packaging the project up wrong, and it's unhappy inside GCP? Just a theory... I really don't know how it all works at this point...

---

## Resolution

It turns out the main culprit here was that (at the time of writing), the instructions for the demos at https://developers.google.com/actions/samples/ indicate to use `gcloud app`, whereas the demos themselves seem to have been 'upgraded'(?) to use `gcloud beta functions`.

Quite confusing if you are new to GCP. (Google would do well to throw more resources at keeping their doco up to date...)

Thanks for the pointer @Prisoner. Answer awarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing two different serverless Google Cloud environments.

`gcloud app` deploys something to Google App Engine. You're not showing all the configuration files, but you probably need more configuration to deploy to an App Engine environment. (You *can* deploy to App Engine running Node, but there is more to it.)

`gcloud beta functions` deploys something to Google Cloud Functions, which is still in beta. (But remember... Google has kept products and services that are working quite well in beta for years...)

Comment: Hmmm. OK. Maybe forget I mentioned "gcloud beta functions". Like I said - Maybe it doesn't actually work. I am just trying to follow the first API.AI Webhook Template example here: https://developers.google.com/actions/samples/ and it says to use "gcloud app deploy".

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to deploy https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-webhook-template-nodejs? It doesn't have `app.yaml` so `gcloud app deploy` should fail because of that. Did you add `app.yaml` to clone of the repository from somewhere else?

Comment: I don't see directions regarding `gcloud app deploy` on the current directions for those projects. They did suggest App Engine before Cloud Functions were released - now they suggest to use Cloud Functions.

Comment: I've added the link to the page I am trying to follow to original question. Also here:  https://developers.google.com/actions/samples/. I have just noticed it says "These instructions assume you are using Google App Engine". Well, I don't know  - They're your Samples Google! My kingdom for a COMPLETE walkthrough... This is verging on the ridiculous...

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Prisoner. Added a Resolution section to Question (Tell me if that's a bad idea). The demos do indeed seem to want to use `gcloud beta functions`. It's the doco page I linked that is out of date (or at a minimum, not very helpful).